# zipWithIndex fails in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have an RDD like this

```
>>> termCounts.collect()
[(2, 'good'), (2, 'big'), (1, 'love'), (1, 'sucks'), (1, 'sachin'), (1, 'formulas'), (1, 'batsman'), (1, 'time'), (1, 'virat'), (1, 'modi')]
```

When am zipping this to create a dictionary, it gives me some random output

```
>>> vocabulary = termCounts.map(lambda x: x[1]).zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
>>> vocabulary
{'formulas': 5, 'good': 0, 'love': 2, 'modi': 9, 'big': 1, 'batsman': 6, 'sucks': 3, 'time': 7, 'virat': 8, 'sachin': 4}
```

Is this the expected output? I wanted to create a dictionary with each word as key and their respective count as value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write like this for word and occurance,

```
vocabulary =termCounts.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).collectAsMap()
```

BTW, the code you have written will print the word and index of pair in list.

Comment: I realised this as my mistake and understood it later, anyways i'll keep this post